# why my cookie is store in local but when i deploy it didn't store. i am using jwt

Tags: javascript, jwt

why my cookie is store in local but when i deploy it didn't store. i am using jwt
Here is my code

```
app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  const userDoc = await User.findOne({ email });
  if (userDoc) {
    const passOk = bcrypt.compareSync(password, userDoc.password);
    if (passOk) {
      jwt.sign(
        {
          email: userDoc.email,
          id: userDoc._id,
        },
        jwtSecret,
        {},
        (err, token) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          res.cookie("token", token).json(userDoc);
        }
      );
    } else {
      res.status(422).json("pass not ok");
    }
  } else {
    res.json("not found");
  }
});

app.get("/profile", (req, res) => {
  const { token } = req.cookies;
  if (token) {
    jwt.verify(token, jwtSecret, {}, async (err, userData) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      const { name, email, _id } = await User.findById(userData.id);
      res.json({ name, email, _id });
    });
  } else {
    res.json(null);
  }
});
```

it didn't store when i deploy it. can someone tell why it is happening